# What is the difference between apache derby vs mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, jakarta-ee, derby

What is the difference between apache derby vs mysql. If there is no much difference in functionality/performance, which is/willbe most popularly used?

Comment: http://database-management-systems.findthebest.com/compare/6-30/Apache-Derby-vs-MySQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Derby is Java based, while MySQL is C/C++. For more details, check out [Wikipedia's comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems)

MySQL has been around for a lot longer than Derby. MySQL has more deployments than Derby. In terms of performance, that's dependent on what you are doing. I've seen a few benchmarks showing Derby to be faster in some aspects, but for the most part, MySQL is faster.

Comment: Just now read in specs that derby does not support datatypes like floating point, date/time, enum .., etc. Is there any alternate types in derby for that?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that Derby is also very mature; it is the open source version of a database named Cloudscape, which dates back to the mid-1990's, and was contributed to Apache by IBM following an acquisition.

Comment: Derby's datatype support is very rich. Where did you read that it doesn't support those datatypes? Here's the datatype list from the docs: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/crefsqlj31068.html

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood it previously